# Text editor has problem with having '<html>' in a post

Tags: posts, post-editor

I'm trying to create a post on a WP 3.8 blog using the text editor that includes a `<pre>` tag with some JavaScript inside it. This JavaScript code happens to have a comment line that contains the string `<html>`. For some reason when I save a draft of the post, WP is adding `</html>` to the end of the code block right before the `</pre>`, right in the text editor.

I have the Crayon syntax highlighter installed, but it shouldn't come into play while I'm editing the post. It's almost like WP sees an open `<html>` tag and is proactively trying to close it. I also tried escaping the angle brackets but the preview of the post showed the actual `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I even tried putting the `<html>` string inside a `<code>` block inside the `<pre>`, but the extra `</html>` was still added.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the admin menu under Settings -> Writing, make sure the option to correct invalid XHTML is unchecked.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Writing_Screen

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is good practice to use invalid XHTML, just uncheck above mentioned box.

Comment: Please reread the question. The OP isn't using invalid code in a theme or plugin; code is being used inside a `pre` tag inside a post.